# How to write Postgres query when filtering a column based on two conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have the following `widgets` table in Postgres:

[image]

(That screenshot is a crude Excel representation of it.) I am trying to write a single SQL query that will return me:

1. The `widgets` record representing the widget with today's earliest load time; or
2. If no `widgets` were loaded today, the one with the earliest load time ever (for the whole table)

So, using the image above:

- The query would first try to return the widget which was loaded first, today (if such a widget exists). In this case, only widgets with an id of 3 and 5003094 (respectively) were loaded today. Of these two, `widget_id = 3` was loaded earlier than the other, so this is the record that the query would return.
- However, if we pretend that those two widgets were not in the table, and furthermore, that no widgets were loaded today, then the query would return `widget_id = 1`, because it was loaded back in 2010.

Here's my initial attempt at the query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(w.loaded_date_time)
FROM
    widgets w
WHERE
    w.loaded_date_time >= now()
    OR
    1=1
```

However, I know right off the bat that this is not syntactically correct. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want one row per widget or one row overall? One row total is rather simple, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### One row total

```
SELECT *
FROM   widgets
ORDER  BY loaded_date_time < now()::date, loaded_date_time
LIMIT  1;
```

.. effectively sorting timestamps of today (+ non-existent future) first, because `boolean` expressions are sorted `FALSE` -> `TRUE` -> `NULL`.

If *future dates* are possible:

```
ORDER  BY
       (loaded_date_time::date = now()::date) DESC NULLS LAST
      ,loaded_date_time
```

`NULLS LAST` is only relevant if `loaded_date_time` can be NULL, which should be disallowed to begin with. Drop the clause in this case.

#### One row per widget

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (widget_id)
       widget_id, loaded_date_time
FROM   widgets
ORDER  BY
       widget_id
      ,(loaded_date_time::date = now()::date) DESC
      ,loaded_date_time;
```

#### Why and how does this work?

- About `DISTINCT ON`:

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- In the `ORDER BY` clause ...
  ... `widget_id` goes first, obviously - has to match the `DISTINCT` clause.
  ... then sort records of "today" first. If there are none, other records move up automatically.
  ... finally, ealier records come sorted first.

  Thereby, the desired row comes first and is picked by `DISTINCT`. All done in one go.
- If you rewrite the expression `(loaded_date_time::date = now()::date)` to

  ```
  (loaded_date_time >= now()::date AND
   loaded_date_time < (now()::date + 1))   -- note: < not: <=
  ```

.. it might be faster with a plain index on `loaded_date_time`. Because, if you have an expression on both sides of the equal sign, you certainly can't use a plain index at all. You should have an index on widget_id (obviously) and probably another on `loaded_date_time`:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON widgets (loaded_date_time)
```

A multi-column index may be a bit faster:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON widgets (widget_id, loaded_date_time);
```

Test with [`EXPLAIN ANLYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html), whether it gets used. It should be, I didn't test. If it doesn't, no point to have it.

Comment: As always beautifully written. But I think you badly misunderstood the question. -1

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Hmmm, I reread the question and my answer, found a typo, but otherwise ... I think my answer fits - in particular the first, simple one. I actually think all other answers (me included at first) have been over-thinking it.

Comment: I had read the _One row per widget_ only at first (it was posted first) and it [does not work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/25ba4/9) as intended. Yes the simplified version is correct.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Well, it does work as advertised, it returns "one row per widget". Wasn't sure whether the OP really just wants 1 row total, which is really very simple. Hence my comment to the question. So I provided an answer for both variants. Also ran a [comparison based on your sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/25ba4/13). Same result, just simpler / faster. But that seems obvious by now.

Comment: The OP is not very clear. `one row per widget`: what is a widget, is it identified by widget_id, or by widget_name? The data shown does not have multiple load_dates per widget{id,name}, so maybe every row is unique enough to report them all in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Break your query up into two queries and `union` them, using a `not exists()` to handle the logic:

```
select * from widget
where <primary criteria>
union
select * from widget
where <secondary criteria>
and not exists (
    select * from widget
    where <primary criteria>
)
```

Coding it like this is also easy to read and maintain, especially if you add yet another way of selecting categories later on.

Comment: I undid the downvote as I do not use to vote in questions where I answer. But you know why.

Comment: @Clodoaldo No, sorry. I have no idea why you downvoted, that's why I asked. I believe my answer to be a good one and I would absolutely code this way if I were writing it for myself. I am interested to know though, because I may learn something from you - I would appreciate knowing your reason.

Comment: You have nothing to learn from me and you know it too. Given the OP's obvious lack of SQL knowledge real code is necessary. Your answer fits between an answer and a comment.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Why is this not an answer? I'm curious... I would be happy to use this code in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application for ranking functions.  The key is the order by:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*,
             row_number() over (partition by widget_id
                                order by isToday, datetime desc) as seqnum
      from (select w.*,
                   (case when cast(widget_loaded_date_time as date) = cast(now() as date)
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as isToday
            from widgets w
           ) w
     ) w
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/25ba4/1)

```
select w.id, w.name, w.loaded_date_time
from (
    select min(loaded_date_time) loaded_date_time
    from widgets
    where loaded_date_time::date = current_date
    union
    select min(loaded_date_time) loaded_date_time
    from widgets
    order by loaded_date_time desc
    limit 1
) s inner join widgets w on w.loaded_date_time = s.loaded_date_time
```